# Cannot get Order by Case to work in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I saw the answer to the other question and that is how I got started, but I can't get my code to work. I think it has to do with the (Price > '0.00') because mysql keeps giving me this error,

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY Price = 0, Price asc, Style asc, Manufacturer asc END WHEN ((Price <= ' at line 8".

```
<?php 
$order = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DivisionOf, Manufacturer, Style, Include,
Fiber, Width, Backing
FROM CarpetInfo

WHERE (DivisionOf='Mohawk') AND (Manufacturer IN ('Aladdin'))
AND CASE
WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes')
THEN ORDER BY Price = 0, Price asc, Style asc, Manufacturer asc
END

WHEN ((Price <= '0.00') OR (Price > '49.95') OR (ShowPrice!='Yes'))
THEN ORDER BY Price = 0, Style asc, Manufacturer asc
END
");
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($order);

mysqli_data_seek($order, 0);
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $order ))
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$info['Include']);?>
```

Comment: Does that even compile in SQL?

Comment: what is syntax error @k1775 show me

Comment: what is the error (if any, but surely) ? or any result but clause does not apply ?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY Price = 0, Price asc, Style asc, Manufacturer asc END WHEN ((Price <= ' at line 8

Comment: The syntax of the CASE Statement is wrong (You have `END` twice in a single `CASE`), and you can't wrap an `ORDER BY` clause inside of a CASE statement anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from my comment.

1. You can't put an entire `ORDER BY` clause into a `CASE` statement
2. One `END` per `CASE` is all that's allowed (at the end of the case statement)

Instead something like the following should work:

```
SELECT DivisionOf, Manufacturer, Style, Include,Fiber, Width, Backing
FROM CarpetInfo
WHERE (DivisionOf='Mohawk') AND (Manufacturer IN ('Aladdin'))
ORDER BY
    /*sort field 1*/
    CASE
        WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes')
            THEN Price
        WHEN ((Price <= '0.00') OR (Price > '49.95') OR (ShowPrice!='Yes'))
            THEN Style
    END asc,
    /*sort field 2*/
    CASE
        WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes')
            THEN Style
        WHEN ((Price <= '0.00') OR (Price > '49.95') OR (ShowPrice!='Yes'))
            THEN Manufacturer
    END asc,
    /*sort field 3*/
    CASE
        WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes')
            THEN Manufacturer       
    END asc;
```

This is a little ugly because you can only have the one field returned from the case statement and then after you `END` the case for that one ORDER BY field you specify the direction.

Also, while I'm not familiar with your data. I think these `CASE` statements could be simplified using `ELSE`:

```
SELECT DivisionOf, Manufacturer, Style, Include,Fiber, Width, Backing
FROM CarpetInfo
WHERE (DivisionOf='Mohawk') AND (Manufacturer IN ('Aladdin'))
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') THEN Price ELSE Style END asc,
    CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') THEN Style ELSE Manufacturer asc,
    CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') THEN Manufacturer END asc;
```

---

Updated: Because we are mixing field types, you are ending up with a lexicographical sort instead of numeric in some instances. Some farting around with the case statements should help:

```
SELECT DivisionOf, Manufacturer, Style, Include,Fiber, Width, Backing
FROM CarpetInfo
WHERE (DivisionOf='Mohawk') AND (Manufacturer IN ('Aladdin'))
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') THEN Price ELSE 0 END asc,
    CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') THEN NULL ELSE Style END asc,
    CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') THEN Style ELSE Manufacturer asc,
    CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price <= '49.95') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') THEN Manufacturer END asc;
```

So now the first sort to hit is either the value in `price` or a 0, then `style` gets moved to the second sort order. You'll have to monkey around with this to get it to work as you please.